# Issue with Sorting a list<xyz<String, String>>, Error: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sorting, compiler-errors, generic-list, invalidoperationexception

I am trying to sort a generic list, and am getting a `InvalidOperationException` error

Does anyone has suggestions on how to rectify it?

`List<XYZ<String, String>>` list is being passed on as a parameter through a function.

```
func( List<XYZ<String, String>> PassedList) {

   PassedList.Sort();
}
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: What's the detail message of the InvalidOperationException?

Comment: XYZ will need to inherit from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.icomparable.aspx if it doesn't allready (if it does, please provide the code for the CompareTo func) and provide a suitable implementation - List<T>.Sort uses the CompareTo function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using linq statement.

rather than using `PassedList.Sort()`, I used the following statement:

```
PassedList = PassedList.OrderBy( x => x.Column1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XYZ should be [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your `XYZ` must implement `IComparable` or (better yet) `IComparable<XYZ<T, U>>`.

If that's not possible, you must either create a class that implements `IComparer` or (again, better yet) `IComparer<XYZ<String, String>>` and use the overload of `Sort()` that takes an instance of such an object, or else use the form that takes a delegate or lamda expression that matches `Comparison<XYZ<String, String>>` (taking two `XZY<String, String>` arguments, and returning `int`).

If the `Sort()` method can't work out which `XYZ` comes before which, then it can't sort them.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I was trying to keep the code as simple as possible and hence tried linq and succeeded

Comment: The linq version deals with it in a slightly different way. If it's a large list (or could be) it may be worth looking at the details more, as there are cases where a lists `Sort()` method is considerably more performant than `OrderBy()`, though also some where the opposite holds. If it's always a small list, then I wouldn't worry about that side of it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future use. thank you for sharing.